# Ajax code error

Tags: php, ajax

I Have Solve The Problem From The Code But Now It Should Return The Array From The User_level But It Return In blank any idea from the error please

```html
<?php
     $user_level = $_GET['user_level'];
     session_start();
     include_once 'dbconnect.php';

     if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
      header("Location: index.php");
     }

    $res=mysql_query("SELECT user_level FROM users where user=".$_SESSION['user']); 

    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
       echo $rows['user_level'];
       // close while loop 
    }
die();
?>
```

Hi hello I have perform this code but it seems to have an error can some one help me with please.

The error is

```
 A página de bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt is not working

 bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt can not process this request for time. 500
```

The Code is

```html
<?php
$user_level = $row['user_level'];
$user_level = $_GET['user_level'];

session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';


if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) //if he isnt logged in
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}

$res=mysql_query("SELECT user_level FROM users where user=".$_SESSION['user']);

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo $user_level;
echo $rows['user_level'];
 }

}



?>
```

Comment: There are two open brackets `{` inside `dbconnect.php` ? You clouse two `}}` at the end of the file. The best thing you could do is debug your code and follow C0dekid advice...

Comment: always indent code which helps you find the non closing or extra brackets

Comment: This seems unusual.I would have returned a json encoded array containing the data set from the query instead of echoing every single value in the loop.

Comment: For a single record no need to use while loop just `mysql_fetch_array()` is fine;

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your brackets and the way that you are getting your information. You have, first, leed of use mysql becasue this extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. Returning at your problem. Try this (Changes are commented):

```
<?php
session_start(); //put your session at the top
require_once 'dbconnect.php'; //not include_once, just require once
$user_level = $_GET['user_level']; 

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) //if he isnt logged in
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
    } //you are finish the if statement

    else //you have to create an else of your if for determinate if your setence if is not complete or not true
    {
//You have an error too in $_SESSION['user']. You have to close in " " or ' ' and use it after in your query. Also and in this example, we will save $_SESSION['user'] in a variable $user.

$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$res = mysql_query("SELECT user_level FROM users where user='$user' ");
//At this point, we will going to create a while for extract information of the query
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        echo $user_level;
        echo $rows['user_level'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Tank You for The Help with i haved a big bug in my code i have soled in other way i go to update

Answer (score 0):

Well I Finish To Discovery The Way To Do With A friend

There It is The Solution For

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 echo "You are not logged in.";
}else{
 
}


$res=mysql_query("SELECT user_level FROM users where user_id=".$_SESSION['user'])or die("We didnt did a sql query".mysql_error());

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($res);

$user_level = $rows['user_level'];

echo $user_level;
 





?>
```

Tanks For The Help